# SSRS running Total On Multiple Columns?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, cumulative-sum

I am creating one SSRS report in which I have one `Tablix` the data of that `Tablix` shown as below,

One Parameter --> Balance = 100

```
firstamt   SecondAmt   ThirdAmt    RunningTotal 
  10         15           20          145
  02         05           01          153
 -30        -20          -03          100
```

So basically my `RunningTotal` fields value should be

```
    RunningTotal = Balance + firstAmt+SecondAmt+thirdAmt and then update
    Balance =  Balance + firstAmt+SecondAmt+thirdAmt (Or RunningTotal)
```

and for then next row should use `Balance= RunningTotal` then calculate the next row runningtotal and so on. I tried using `custom code`, `RunningValue` but still got no luck.

Any help would be great, Thanks. And also my reporting server is 2008.

(In case of confusion feel free to comment.)

I tried following Custom code but it doesn't work

```
 public dim finalRunningTotal as decimal = 0
 public function CalculateRunningTotal (totalAmount as decimal, CheckAmount as decimal,pstAmount as decimal) as decimal
     dim valueToReturn as decimal = finalRunningTotal + totalAmount + CheckAmount +pstAmount 
     finalRunningTotal = valueToReturn 
     return valueToReturn 
end function
```

Comment: You have three amounts, will this always be three (or a fixed number, anyway) or will it be a changing number of amounts every time the report runs?

Comment: amount will come from the database so there values will be different each time but the columns will be same three columns

Comment: @IanPreston basically I want a way to update the Balance Parameter for each row so the expression of sum of all three columns with balance parameter will work for running total calculation.

Comment: What is the source for Amt-columns? Is there any way to calculate all these SUMs inside the source and only add parameter value in the report?

Comment: @AlexPeshik Yes i can update the source to get the sum all amount columns in one column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one of doing it - use an expression like:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!FirstAmt.Value + Fields!SecondAmt.Value + Fields!ThirdAmt.Value
        , Sum
        , Nothing)
    + Parameters!Balance.Value
```

You may have to change `Nothing` to a different Scope depending on how your table is set up.

Works for me in a simple example:

[image]

[image]

Here the example is as above.

[image]

[image]

To simplify this you could add a Calculated Field to the Dataset like:

```
=Fields!FirstAmt.Value + Fields!SecondAmt.Value + Fields!ThirdAmt.Value
```

Which makes the `RunningValue` expression simpler:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!MyCalculatedField.Value
        , Sum
        , Nothing)
    + Parameters!Balance.Value
```

Comment: I will try and let you know.